# PL/SQL cursor for loop and record not working

Tags: database, plsql, cursor, record

I have the following problem. I'm trying to check a number (bsn), if it's in the database or not. If it's not in the database it should give me an error, however now I'm getting always an error even if the number exists in the database. It worked fine with only one number in the database, but with more... That's the problem. Oh and I'm working with APEX, so I use this as a process.

```
   create or replace PROCEDURE CONTROLE_BSN IS

CURSOR c_klanten
  IS
    SELECT bsn
    FROM klant;

    v_bsn VARCHAR2(10) := V('P7_BSN');

    e_geen_bsn EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

  FOR r_record IN c_klanten
  LOOP
    IF r_record.bsn != v_bsn THEN
      RAISE e_geen_bsn;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN e_geen_bsn THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'This bsn-number does not exists.');

END CONTROLE_BSN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is flowed. As soon as you have two different `bsn` in your table, your test will be true for at least one of them:

```
  FOR r_record IN c_klanten
  LOOP
    IF r_record.bsn != v_bsn THEN  --< when N different records, 
                                   --  this is true for at least N-1 of them
      RAISE e_geen_bsn;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

Maybe you should go for something a little bit simpler than that. Why not write your cursor like this instead:

```
CURSOR c_klanten
  IS
    SELECT count(*) n
    FROM klant
    WHERE nbc = v_bsn;
```

That way, you will easily get the number of matching `bsn`. Either 0, 1 or more. And then perform the appropriate action.

Comment: Now I get the following problem  IF r_record.bsn != v_bsn THEN is not accepted, because he can't find r.record.bsn?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following would help:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CONTROLE_BSN IS
  CURSOR c_klanten(p_bsn) IS
    SELECT count(*) as bsn_count
      FROM klant
      where bsn = p_bsn;

  v_bsn VARCHAR2(10) := V('P7_BSN');

  e_geen_bsn EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  FOR r_record IN c_klanten(v_bsn)
  LOOP
    IF r_record.bsn_count = 0 THEN
      RAISE e_geen_bsn;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;    
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN e_geen_bsn THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'This bsn-number does not exists.');
END CONTROLE_BSN;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem by replacing where bsn = v_bsn and just using select bsn instead of count(*). Somehow this seems to work fine!